# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DoesNotExist'

Tags: python, html, css, django

I would appreciate some help in receiving data from a database by viewing it in another page as you click onto the search button. The problem I am receiving is an AttributeError. after clicking into that button

I have tried to look at similar issues.

***Views.py***

```
def act_results(request):
    '''
    display the acts suitable for a particular user
    '''
    template = loader.get_template('polls/act_results.html')
    try:
       Act = request.GET.get('Act')
       data = Act.objects.get(act__name=Act)
       return HttpResponse(template.render({'Act':Act},request))
    except Act.DoesNotExist:
       return HttpResponse(template.render({'error_msg':'Act does not exist for this Festival'}))
```

***models.py***

```
class Act(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
   stage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   start_time = models.TimeField()
   end_time = models.TimeField()
   date = models.DateTimeField()

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

***act_results.html***

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Acts available</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Act :  {{ Acts }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

I expect to receive all the information about that act in the html page.

As of now I am receiving an error.

Comment: Which line is giving the exception? `data = Act.objects.get(act__name=Act)`? Why not catch and handle the exception there if that doesn't return data? It seems like you expect it to always return data when really that might not be the case.

Comment: You assigned `Act = request.GET.get('Act')`, this is really one of the main reasons to use the PEP-8 naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You've overwritten the name `Act` by assigning it to the result of the `request.GET.get()` call. Use a different name there.

Also you should be passing the result of the db lookup, not the request item, to the context. And `template.render` doesn't take the request as a second parameter. You should be using the standalone `render` shortcut anyway.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
...

def act_results(request):
   value = request.GET.get('Act')
   try:
       item = Act.objects.get(act__name=value)
       context = {'Act': item}
   except Act.DoesNotExist:
       context = {'error_msg':'Act does not exist for this Festival'}
   return render(request, 'polls/act_results.html', context)
```

I don't know what the CSV has to do with anything, though. And the lookup filter is suspect; does your Act model have a relationship with another model via an `act` field? Seems unlikely. And your template should have `{{ Act }}`, not `{{ Acts }}`.

Honestly, the summary here is that you really need to take more care with your code.